# How improve Watson Speech to Text speaker label

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, speech-to-text

I'm using Watson Speech to Text on my projects, and I have questions.

- How can I improve the quality of speaker labeling?
- Does acoustic custom model effect this improvement?

  Please give me some advice.

Comment: **My use case is like a small meeting for 4~10 speakers , but in each recording, the speakers always change (over 100 people in total). I only need to identify 4~10 speakers in each meeting, and not need to identify all (over 100) speakers in the long term

Answer (score 0):

Acoustic model customization will only have a moderate impact in the quality of the speaker labels. It should get better, but do not expect drastic improvements.

What is your use case for speaker labels? how many speakers do you have in your recording?

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
I read documents and references again, but couldn't find explanations about speaker labels at acoustic model customization section. 
My use case is like a small meeting for 4~10 speakers , but in each recording, the speakers always change (over 100 people in total). 
I only need to identify 4~10 speakers in each meeting, and not need to identify all (over 100) speakers in the long term.

Comment: the speaker labels feature typically works much better when there are only two speakers... that said you can try and see

Comment: OK, I got it.
I will try and if I get good results, will post it this community.
Thanks a lot.